# How to model a complex relationship involving a Weak Entity and entities related to its parents?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, erd

I'm working on a database schema involving four tables: `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. The relationships among these tables are as follows:

- Table `A` can have one or many records from Table `B`.
- Table `C` can have one or many records from Table `D`.
- There is a many-to-many relationship between Tables `A` and `C`, forming a weak entity (joint table) "`AC`".

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE B (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    a_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES A(id)
);

CREATE TABLE C (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE D (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    c_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES C(id)
);

CREATE TABLE AC (
    a_id INT,
    c_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (a_id, c_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES A(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES C(id)
);
```

[image: schema visualization]

**My requirements :** For each `AC` record, I need to link the *`B`s associated with its `A`* to the *`D`s associated with its `C`*.

**Explanations :** This looks like a ternary relationship involving `AC`, `B` and `D` : In the context of an `AC` record, a `B` needs to be linked to a `D`. But we have the added constraints of the `B` needing to belong to the `A` of the `AC` record, and the `D` needing to belong to the `C` of the same `AC` record.

**What I've tried :** I've tried creating a simple "assignment" table which references AC, B and D. However, I couldn't enforce the constraints mentioned above.

```sql
CREATE TABLE assignment (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ac_a_id INT,  -- Foreign key referencing 'a_id' in AC
    ac_c_id INT,  -- Foreign key referencing 'c_id' in AC
    b_id INT,     -- Foreign key referencing 'id' in B
    d_id INT,     -- Foreign key referencing 'id' in D

    FOREIGN KEY (ac_a_id, ac_c_id) REFERENCES AC(a_id, c_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES B(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (d_id) REFERENCES D(id)
);
```

What would be a good approach to model this relationship? Are there specific SQL constructs or design patterns that would best fit this scenario?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please update the question providing full table descriptions (ddl), sample data, and results you are expect. Additionally. what have you tried and those results. Post all as formatted text - **no images**. See [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) for creating formatted text or even better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk).

Comment: `B` and `D` are linked. `AC` is transitively associated with `B` whenever `AC.a_id` and `B.a_id` have the same value because each references the same row in `A`. `AC` is transitively associated with `D` whenever `AC.c_id` and `D.c_id` have the same value because each references the same row in `C`. Creating an `assignment` table to explicitly link `B` and `D` is redundant. The "constraint" that linked `B`s and `Ds` must belong to a row in `AC` is captured by these transitive equivalences. My answer demonstrates these transitive associations and the lack of a need for additional constraints.

Answer (score 0):

While `AC` is a weak entity, it is more properly referred to as an associative table (also called a bridge table). There isn't any need for an "assignment" table referencing `AC`, `B`, and `D`, you've already modeled the relationship between `B` and `D`. To demonstrate, run the following commands to create and populate the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE b (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  a_id integer REFERENCES a(id)
);

CREATE TABLE c (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE d (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  c_id integer REFERENCES c(id)
);

CREATE TABLE ac (
  a_id integer REFERENCES a(id),
  c_id integer REFERENCES c(id),
  CONSTRAINT ac_pk PRIMARY KEY (a_id, c_id)
);

INSERT INTO a(id)
SELECT generate_series(100, 109);

INSERT INTO b(id, a_id)
VALUES (200, 100),
       (201, 101),
       (202, 101),
       (203, 103);

INSERT INTO c(id)
SELECT generate_series(300, 309);

INSERT INTO d(id, c_id)
VALUES (400, 300),
       (401, 301),
       (402, 302),
       (403, 302);

INSERT INTO ac(a_id, c_id)
VALUES (100, 300),
       (101, 301),
       (102, 301),
       (103, 302),
       (104, 302),
       (104, 303);
```

The following query returns the associated rows from `B` and `D` through `AC`:

```
SELECT ac.a_id, b.id AS b_id, ac.c_id, d.id AS d_id
  FROM ac
  JOIN b ON ac.a_id = b.a_id
  JOIN d ON ac.c_id = d.c_id
  ORDER BY ac.a_id, b.id, ac.c_id, d.id;
```

The output from the preceding query is:

| a_id | b_id | c_id | d_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 |
| 101 | 201 | 301 | 401 |
| 101 | 202 | 301 | 401 |
| 103 | 203 | 302 | 402 |
| 103 | 203 | 302 | 403 |

The following query demonstrates the "link" between `B` and `D`:

```
SELECT b.id AS b_id, d.id AS d_id
  FROM ac
  JOIN b ON ac.a_id = b.a_id
  JOIN d ON ac.c_id = d.c_id
  WHERE b.id = 203
  ORDER BY b.id, d.id;
```

The output shows that the row in `B` with `id` = 203 is associated with `D` rows with `id`s of 402 and 403:

| b_id | d_id |
| --- | --- |
| 203 | 402 |
| 203 | 403 |

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I think there's a misunderstanding. My question is about linking `B`s to `D`s through the `AC` entity, which seems like a ternary relationship involving `B`, `D`, and `AC`.

I am not looking to simply query all the `B` and `D` rows associated with an `AC` record. Instead, I want to be able to link those rows together in the context of each `AC` record. I hope this clarifies my intention.

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Thanks for your edits. I do understand that `B` and `D` are transitively linked. In your example, `B` with id 203 is associated with `D` rows 402 and 403.

What I want to do is, beyond this transitive relationship, have a way to specifically link for example `B` 203 to `D` 402, but not to `D` 403.

Comment: The requirement to directly link rows in `B` to rows in `D` with the constraint that their associated references to `A` and `C` must have a corresponding row in `AC` was not explicately stated in the original post. There isn't a native constraint capability in PostgreSQL to enforce such a requirement; however, triggers can be used to implement the constraint. Besides preventing associations between rows in `B` and `D` without a corresponding row in `AC`, the triggers would also need to prevent deletions from, or updates to, `AC` that would invalidate existing `B` to `D` associations.